# Is there a spell area of effect sizes write up?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, homebrew

I am working on A D20 Mod for a homebrew campaign setting. At the moment I'm working on the magic. The [SRD](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html) has a breakdown of the spell ranges...

1. Close Range: 25 feet +5 per caster level.
2. Medium Range: 100 feet + 10 per caster level.
3. Long Range: 400 feet + 40 per caster level.

What I'm seeking is a similar breakdown for area of effect sizes?
Is there book or magazine/web article that list AOE's in manner similar to spell range is.

Something like...

Small Area. X feet +X per caster level.

Medium Area.  X feet +X per caster level.

Large Area.  X feet +X per caster level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no list of standard areas. The areas of spell effects are always defined specifically for that spell in its description. There is no consistency you can leverage there. If you want one for your system, you will have to write one.

Answer (score 2):

If I undertstood correctly what you want, I'm afraid the answer is no.

There are some spells (most of them shapeable) like Wall of Stone or Wall of Fire that have an area of X-ft. square/level or X-ft. line/level though.

Most spells have an already definite spell area that do not progress at all with caster level, they need a metamagic like Widen Spell to do so, but like I said, there are some that do. However, the breakdown you're looking for does not exist in official rulebooks or Dragon Magazines. I'm not confident to say the same about 3rd parties books, so I won't.